# Various errors in submitting offers

Tags: javascript-sdk, offer, manageofferoperation

This is my code:

```
var sourceSecretKey = 'REDACTED';

var sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sourceSecretKey);
var sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();


var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');
StellarSdk.Network.usePublicNetwork();

server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
    .then(function(account) {            
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, {                
        fee: StellarSdk.BASE_FEE        
    })
        // Add a manageOffer operation
        .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageBuyOffer({
        selling: new StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        buying: new StellarSdk.Asset('ABC', 'GDFBWP6GYJE7PMA4HVLLSPG6346Z67XAME7C2WJIUIA5HGJEJWFWIBPI'),
        amount: '0.001',
        price: '15.6250000',
        offerId: '0'
        }))
        .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text('Hello'))
        .setTimeout(180)
        .build();

    transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);

     console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));    

    server.submitTransaction(transaction)
        .then(function(transactionResult) {

         console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionResult, null, 2));
         console.log('\nSuccess! View the transaction at: ');
         console.log(transactionResult._links.transaction.href);

        })
        .catch(function(err) {
         console.log('An error has occured:');
         console.log(err);                                                                            

        });
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
     console.error(e);

    });
```

On submit, it shows an error:

```
TypeError: buyAmount argument must be of type String, represent a positive number and have at most 7 digits after the decimal
at Function.manageBuyOffer (stellar-sdk.js:43384)
at [.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageBuyOffer({]
```

I changed `manageBuyOffer` to `manageSellOffer`. It goes through, but the order book for the pair is not updated to reflect this offer. I tried doing the same transaction on `stellarx.com`, and the transaction went through and the order got reflected in the order book.

I tried another transaction, this time switching the pairs. The amount was `"1"` and the price `"0.0540000"`. I got an error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (stellar-sdk.js:27374)
at settle (stellar-sdk.js:46113)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (stellar-sdk.js:27236)
```

I am using the JavaScript SDK and running in the browser.
I did the same transaction on `stellarx.com`, and the transaction went through as expected, and the order got reflected in the order book.
I wonder where all these errors are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide `buyAmount` instead of `amount` in `manageBuyOffer` operations.

The 400 error on the testnet may be cause by different reasons: no trustline, not enough funds, invalid signers, etc. Check the `extras.result_codes` field in the error object itself.

Comment: It may be a novice's question, but how do I get the {extras.result_codes} to appear in the console.log? What will I add in my code above?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code that handles exceptions and check the error object itself or print the error to console using `JSON.stringify()`. Like `try { horizon.loadAccount('GAB...') } catch(e) { console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, '  ')) }`

Comment: This part of the code is the one catching the error and it does not return `extras.result_codes`:

`.catch(function(err) {
         console.log('An error has occured:');
         console.log(err);                                                                            
        });`

Comment: I did `console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, ' ')); ` and I can't quite find the `extras.result_codes`.